# Why does my script periodically freeze while deleting millions of files?

Tags: python, linux, performance, filesystems, delete-file

My goal was to delete 10 million temp files from `dir`. So, I tried to write a Python script to do this. The first scenario looked like [that](http://pastebin.com/1nkBtzLK):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys
dirname = os.getcwd() if len(sys.argv) == 1 else sys.argv[1]
deleteConfirm = raw_input('Delete all files from dir ' + str(dirname) + ' (y/n)? ')
if(deleteConfirm not in ['y','Y']):
    os._exit(0)

counter = 0
flist = os.listdir(dirname)
for file in flist:
    os.remove(os.path.join(dirname, file))
    counter+=1
    if(0==counter%1000):
        sys.stdout.write('\rDeleted %d files' % counter)
        sys.stdout.flush()

print '\nDeleted %d files' % counter
```

This code works, but I found that it stops every 10-15 seconds and does not work for minute or so. For example, first few seconds scenario quickly outputs numbers of deleted files - it deletes 28 000 files for just 3-5 seconds, but then its output stops on "Deleted 28000 files" and waiting for long time - minute or so. Then output again quickly updates, and again thousands of files deleted in few seconds. But then again it stops and waiting for something. I think this is due to locked files, so i tried to write new scenario, using python3 and multiprocessing module, to delete files in few processes. I thought it might help, because even if one process waiting for some file to unclock, other processes will do theirs job.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/3bYWphfE) is the new script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os, sys, time
from multiprocessing import Pool
dirname = os.getcwd() if len(sys.argv) == 1 else sys.argv[1]
procNum = 5 if len(sys.argv) < 3 else sys.argv[2]
deleteConfirm = input('Delete all files from dir ' + str(dirname) + ' (y/n)? ')
if(deleteConfirm not in ['y','Y']):
    sys.exit()

def main():
    flist = os.listdir(dirname) 
    count = len(flist)
    if count < 100000:
        counter = 0
        for file in flist:
                os.remove(os.path.join(dirname, file))
                counter+=1
                if(0==counter%1000):
                    sys.stdout.write('\rDeleted %d files' % counter)
                    sys.stdout.flush()
            print('\rDeleted %d files' % counter)
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            workers = Pool(processes=procNum)       
            result = workers.imap_unordered(delfile,flist)
        workers.close()
        while True:
                    time.sleep(5)
                    completed = result._index
                    if completed == count:
                        print('')
                        break
                    sys.stdout.write('\rRemoved %d files' % result._index)
            workers.join()

def delfile(fname):
    os.remove(os.path.join(dirname,fname))
```

I tried this new script, but it stops every few seconds, as previous scenario. I can't figure out, why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: If you really have 10 millions of files in a directory, that's likely to be a problem for your filesystem.  It's possible that you're hitting some bottleneck in the filesystem itself.

Comment: Few OSes are designed around "delete 10 million files" as a common use case.  Why so many files?  Are all these files in a single directory?

Comment: Agree with @mgilson that the issue is likely with Linux, not Python. I don't know how the inner workings of `os.remove` work, but it might have something to do with hitting a shell expansion block.  Try passing in this command to the shell instead of `os.remove` - see if that helps `find . -exec /bin/rm {} \;`  (this should remove any shell expansion issues)

Comment: @Andenthal Unlikely. `os.remove()` is lower layer than shell, so using shell will probably add complexity instead of removing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The details are in the Linux documentation, assuming you're using Linux (other OSes may be different): see for example https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt.

Linux handles writes to disk by creating "dirty pages", which are sections of memory that are pending a physical copy to the disk.  The physical copy comes later.  That's why `os.remove()` is usually very fast: it will just create or modify a page in memory and leave the physical copy for later.  (If, soon, we do another `os.remove()` that needs to change the same page of memory, then we win: no need to write this page several times to disk.)

Normally, a daemon called "pdflush" wakes up periodically to do this write to disk.  But if a process generates really a lot of dirty pages, then at one point the kernel will stop it (during a random one of the `os.remove()` calls) and force the write to disk to occur now, for some fraction of the pending pages.  It only allows the program to continue when the dirty pages are again below a reasonable threshold.  Likely, "pdflush" will then immediately continue writing the rest.  Obviously, if your program continues to generate dirty page, it will reach again the upper limit and be paused again.

This is what causes the pauses in your process.  It's a side-effect of how the kernel works.  You can ignore it: physically, the disk is busy all the time.